# Why does `lea esi, dword [edx + ecx * 4]` produce an error when assembled using NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Why does `lea esi, dword [edx + ecx * 4]` produce an error when assembled using NASM?

I get the error:

> insertion_sort.asm:19: error: mismatch in operand sizes

However, the purpose of `lea` is just to load the address of `dword [edx + ecx * 4]`, so even thus the reference is for a DWORD value it should not matter?

On the other hand,

```
mov eax, dword [edi]
```

works perfectly fine as expected. Here I declare that `[edi]` references a DWORD value.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `lea`, the size specifier is not relevant. You're not loading anything from memory - you're just calculating an address (doesn't even need to be something you plan to use as an address - you can use `lea` for general arithmetic). There would be no difference between `lea esi, byte [edx]` and `lea esi, dword [edx]`, so there's no point in having a size specifier at all.

It's actually redundant in your `mov` example, because the size can be deduced from the destination operand. But in the case of `mov` it's actually relevant in some cases (e.g. `mov byte [edi], 1`), whereas in the case of `lea` it isn't.

Note that you *can* have `lea` calculate a 16-bit address and zero-extend it into a 32-bit destination register (or calculate a 32-bit address and truncate it into a 16-bit destination register). But the address size is according to Intel's manual determined by *"the attribute of the code segment"*, rather than something you specify in the instruction.

Comment: So, the error produced by NASM is because "there is no point in having a size specifier at all"?
Shouldn't NASM just ignore the specifier then, and don't generate an error?

Comment: Someone with better knowledge of the NASM source code would have to answer that. I could certainly see a danger in silently ignoring unexpected tokens, as the programmer's expectation of what the assembler has produced might differ from reality. I'll agree that the error message seems a bit cryptic.

Comment: Thank you @Michael.

Comment: Note that you can use an *address size override* to change the address size to the opposite of what the code segment indicates.

Comment: Actually you can specify the address size in the instruction. If you use `lea eax, [bx + di]` then assembler generates an instruction with the address size override prefix (assuming BITS 32 is in effect) that FUZxxl mentioned.

Comment: Would you provide an answer elaborating on your comment @FUZxxl?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I don't know how elaborating on my comment would answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with this a little, I believe that the `dword` prefix is what trips up `nasm`. Just leave it out and nasm is happy.